# JQuery $.post() and curl

Tags: javascript, jquery, curl

This is what the GroupMe API (https://dev.groupme.com/docs/v3#messages_create) asks for:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"source_guid": "frgfre", "text":"alala"}' https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups/ID/messages?token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Please assume ID is a valid group id and the token is also valid and works. How exactly would I convert that to a $.post() request and run it from the console of a browser? Here is what I have that is not working in IE when Cross Domain is enabled and it is a trusted site:

```
var t = {"source_guid": "frgfre", "text":"alala"};
$.post("https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups/ID/messages?token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", t);
//I have also tried t.toString() as well but it didn't work
```

If that can't be converted (or what I have right now is correct), where would I run the first bit of code?

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Are you getting a Cross Origin error? Does GroupMe support JSONP?

Comment: I'm getting an internal server error. The get requests go through fine, as do the posts that don't require any attachments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.post` posts the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. If the API requires it to be JSON, you need to use `$.ajax` to override the default.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups/ID/messages?token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    data: JSON.stringify(t),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false
});
```